# How do I find a casual wear tailor?

Tags: clothing

I'm incredibly frustrated at clothes shopping and finding it impossible to find anything to replace my worn out clothes.

I'm at the point where I'd happily pay to get measured and have something made for me but I can't find anywhere/anyone to do it. The place I got my coat altered a couple years ago isn't great as they'd expect me to sort out all the haberdashery myself and I just can't deal with the stress. I just want some new clothes I don't hate.

Comment: What have you already tried in terms of finding a suitable tailor?

Comment: Mostly googling for 'casualwear tailor' but not really getting anywhere. There's only one tailor in the city where I work that does women's wear (even formal) and I talk about them above. There's a company in Bournemouth that does something similar to what I'm looking for off the rack, but it's too far away to get fitted. The next closest city to me is London, which is probably outside my price range but floods out anything else.

Comment: 1.75 million people live in Montreal, Canada. It's not a small town. It's pretty well known for its fashion industry. Of all the types of tailors here (suit, fine, luxury, bespoke, custom, etc.), not one "casual wear" tailor is listed. Don't limit you choices with such adjectives such as "casual wear." Use a thesaurus for other words to use. What happens when you look for dress maker, seamstress, or alterations?

Answer (score 3):

Be the tailor - not as extreme as it sounds.  I am a guy whose shirts never fit well.  Those that fit in the chest poof out at the waist.  Youtube has many videos about altering clothes, but I did not know how to sew.  Then I found the SewingMaster Youtube channel.  This lady created beginning sewing videos for specific machines.  I got a Brother 6000i and went through the whole series.  Now when I buy a shirt, I just add a couple of darts.  Recently, I took in my sport coat.

Another thing that helped was to note which brands fit me best.  I know that if I order a certain size shirt from Land's End, it will fit correctly in the sleeves and collar, and need only the darts for the waist.  Some alterations are more difficult than others, so you choose items that will take the least effort.

Comment: Excellent idea. I do this too, for me and my SO.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options that may help you.

- Ask family and friends.  Someone may know someone who has had this service done, or you may be surprised that a friend of a friend makes casual clothes.
- Place an ad on a site like Craigslist.  It may take a few weeks to get a response, but it's worth a try.  Be clear about your goals, your location, and your budget.
- Ask at a fabric store.  Some of the employees themselves may be interested in side work, and would be able to help you.  They may also know of regular customers who do that kind of work regularly but are hard to find.
- Find conventions, gatherings, membership groups, etc. for local clothes makers. Ask them for referrals.
- Research whether any nearby schools offer clothes-making programs. The teachers / professors may be able to refer you to some of their exceptional former students, or may want to make clothes for you themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The spousal unit has his clothes made by an online tailoring service. They sent a list of measurements and I measured him very carefully (they suggested having a dressmaker do it if we couldn't). They have the measurements saved and of course he has to tell them if he changes size.

Anyway, he orders his trousers using a GUI with clickers for material, colour, style, etc, and a week later they turn up. There is a guarantee so he can send things back if they don't fit. He is totally happy with this arrangement (me too, now I don't have to shorten everything he buys).

The service is much cheaper than expected - comparable with buying good clothes in a quality shop.

There are several websites who do this, and his is in Germany, so I won't advertise it here. You can find on in your country.